# Simple shell script needed to move database files

Tags: shell, shell-script, rename, database

I am using **MySQL** on **Ubuntu** machine.

I need to physically move around the database files under `/var/lib/mysql/` (this is where all the databases directories are located).

Say I have two databases, **db_1** and **db_2**, so I can see two directories(`db_1/` and `db_2/`) under the path `/var/lib/mysql/` . Under each of these two database directory, there are many `.frm` `.MYD` `.MYI` files which holds all the tables' informations of the database.

For example, under `db_1/` directory there are following files:

```
/var/lib/mysql/db_1# ls

cars.frm 
cars.MYD 
cars.MYI

customers.frm
customers.MYD
customers.MYI

departments.frm
departments.MYD
departments.MYI

...
```

which holds *cars*, *customers*, *departments* tables' info.

I need a shell script to do the following simple task:

1. make a new direcotry named `db_1_temp` under `/var/lib/mysql/`
2. move files related with *cars* and *customers* tables in `db_1` directory to `db_1_temp` direcotry
3. move files in `db_2` directory to `db_1` direcotry

**NOTE**, user need **root** privilege to access  `/var/lib/mysql/`

I need these things in a .sh file so I can run it in another application.

Sorry that I do not know shell script, but need this thing. Appreciate if anyone can give a help, this shell script should not be hard I think. I try to extract some time to learn shell, as now I am quite busy with other software development. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rename the databases directories directly. Instead, dump the database out, create a new database name (which, in turn, will create the new directory name) and then dump the database back into the new database name:

```
mysqldump -u username -p  olddatabase > olddbdump.sql
mysqladmin -u username -p create newdatabase
mysql -u username -p newdatabase < olddbdump.sql
```

Once you verified that the database is functional, you can drop the datase:

```
mysqladmin -u username -p drop oldatabase.
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name) for reference.

In your case, you probably want to create a tmp database, dump the db_1 database into that temp database, drop and recreate the db_2 database, then dump the db_2 database into the newly empty db_1 database.

Comment: But I only want to have part of the tables in the database, how to dump out part of the database ?

Comment: Then use mysqldump -u username -p olddatabase tablename > oldtablename.sql to export an individual table, then mysql -u username -p newdatabase < oldtablename.sql to import.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's just moving files, so nothing complicated -- just 3 mv command

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /var/lib/mysql/db_1_temp
mv /var/lib/mysql/db_1/cars* /var/lib/mysql/db_1_temp
mv /var/lib/mysql/db_1/customers* /var/lib/mysql/db_1_temp
mv /var/lib/mysql/db_2/* /var/lib/mysql/db_1_temp
```

But it if you plan to use the new database, you're better off with creating a new empty db and then use mysqldump to import tables you need.

Comment: Hi, savamane, I tried your command, but I got the following error: mv: cannot stat `/var/lib/mysql/db_1/*': No such file or directory. But I have that directory db_1/